# Disable navigation on clicking Sub report from main Crystal Repert - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreport

How to disable navigation to the sub-report when clicked on it? I have report with 1 sub-report that displays Company information and I need to disable it once it has been clicked by Customer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

it can be disable from crystal report viewer control.Use

```
CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDrillDown = False
```

this will work for crystal report 2008 or above.

**Edits:**

AS per comments by Question owner,in order to disable just navigation.there is no defined way.but it can be achieved by some other means.

"Create an empty text cell that is as wide as the report, and use it to "cover" the clickable fields to prevent drilldown.
       Seriously, this is the only way we've found to do this. This is also documented on the BusObj support knowledge base (http://support.businessobjects.com/library/kbase/articles/c2013204.asp)"

for more information,Refer the link [Disable Navigation](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=338850&sid=be20b222298760c12d8ab4c594a4f502)

Comment: I don't need to hide Sub report. I just want to disable it by navigating to sub report